# Going all the way with Miranda.... is it possible?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I finished the game long time ago, and tried all along to keep Miranda happy hoping she's the One.

I was really disappointed in the end when their relationship was still pretty much vague and they didn't even come close to any action, apart of some empty talk of them being together.

Have I done something wrong? I went for a while for Jack but once it was either her or Miranda, I chose Miranda.

Any ideas or tips are welcome, I might play again just for fun. :)

Comment: /me grabs popcorn and beer.

Comment: -She was actually wearing a bra under that suit

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe you were 'locked-in' with a different character without realizing it. Here are the dialogue options from the [wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Romance)

> For a male Shepard, a love interest is
> "locked in" once you express interest
> at the following dialogue points:
>
> Jack: "I want to talk about us."
> To prevent locking-in, say "Never mind".
>
> Tali: "I want to talk about you." at
> the point where she beckons you toward
> the drive core. To prevent locking-in,
> say "So you're not interested?"
> followed by "I need to think about
> this."
>
> Miranda: "Can we talk?" at the
> point where she says "I don't know
> what this is, if it's just stress, or
> blowing off steam, or..." you can not
> opt out; every option results in
> either becoming locked-in, or the
> relationship being broken off
> permanently. Hope you saved before the
> conversation!
>
> At this point you know
> that Shepard has successfully 'locked
> in' that romance.
>
> Shepard can still
> express an interest in other crew
> members. However, the new love
> interest will 'challenge' Shepard's
> love-triangle and force Shepard to
> dump the 'locked-in' option in order
> to be with them. Once a potential
> relation is at the 'challenge' part,
> there is no way to express disinterest
> in them no matter what Shepard choose.
> However, if Shepard dumps someone who
> is 'locked in', that romance option
> will never be available. A romance
> scene with the 'locked-in' character
> will be shown when the Normandy SR-2
> proceeds through the Omega 4 Relay.
> Although it is possible to have a
> sexual encounter with Jack before
> this, it does not count as a romance.
>
> If Shepard and the love interest
> survive the suicide mission, it is
> possible to invite him or her up to
> the Captain's quarters to either sit
> with them on the couch, or lie with
> them on the bed.

Comment: Thanks, don't remember for sure what I've done but this probably explains what happened.

Comment: :) yup this stuff is pretty algorithmic, even for dragon age, one bungled selection and all that talking is wasted

Comment: @bronze talking about dragon age, I did have "full" relationship with two characters - so in that aspect, that game was better. :P

Comment: yeah.. but i was talking about the stupid option "I think you should leave" which screws everything up. god knows how many times I accidentally selected that and had to restart my dungeon exploration

Comment: We want proof, we want proof!

Comment: I had two full relationships in ME2: Miranda and Tali.  I thought I was just being nice, letting Tali down easy, but apparently that just made her a challenger.

Comment: *SPOILER* for those wanting proof, [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zjLH7ploJI) is the vid